# Uncontrollable platform spawning

Tags: unity, c#, mobile

I made simple spawner like this:

```
void Update() {

    if (PlatformPosition.spawnNewPlatform) {
        NewPlatform();
    }
}

public void NewPlatform() {

    if (active) {
        newTransform = transform;
        Instantiate(prefabs[Random.Range(0, prefabs.Length)], newTransform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

And so it looks like my platform script:

```
public static bool spawnNewPlatform = true;

void Awake() {
    spriteSize = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    offscreenX = (Screen.width / PixelPerfect.pixelsToUnit) / 2 + offset;
}

void Update () {

    pos = transform.position;
    posX = pos.x;

    if (posX <= -offscreenX) {

        spawnNewPlatform = true;
    }
    else {
        spawnNewPlatform = false;
    }
}
```

Now when I start the "game" the spawner create unexpected number of platforms. Sometimes it's 2 clones sometimes it's 10...
I don't understand what is the problem and how to fix it. Is it frame rate issue?

Comment: Have you made sure that the line of code runs only once?

Comment: How is the position of the spawned platform determined?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you only have one spawner, it doesn't look like the spawner could be instantiating 10 platforms. However, it's definitely possible that you'll get two. On the frame after the platform is instantiated, if `Spawner.Update()` gets called before `Platform.Update()`, then `spawnNewPlatform` will still be `true` and another one will get created.

Try setting `spawnNewPlatform = false` within `Platform.Awake()`. That way, when a platform is spawned, it will immediately prevent spawning of any other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `if(spawnNewPlatform) return;` to the top of your platform `Update()` method.

Also if it's a scrolling level and not a static single screen level then the platforms may be hitting the respawn point early. If that's the case you may want to use `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint()`

`void Update() 
{
        Vector3 screenPos = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position);
        Debug.Log("target is " + screenPos.x + " pixels from the left");
}`

This will convert the world coordinates to those matching your screen so that you can check when they're out of sight.

Link to help: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html